# Is there any way to Run Lambda/Step function code from Account A -> And have the function access to S3 bucket in the Account B?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, lambda, cloud, devops

I have added the bucket policies and from Account A -> I can access buckets at Account B.
Is there any proper structured method of how the same can be achieved by A lambda function or a step function from Account A to Account B.
I have created the Lambda execution role too, but not sure how to do and what to do.
please help

Answer (score 0):

Find the answer below at the link, But generally speaking it did not take long to google it...
https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-function-assume-iam-role/